# qooxdoo VirtualTree setMaxHeight for item like in normal Tree

Tags: tree, height, qooxdoo

In qooxdoo's tree you can setMaxHeight for each tree item:

var tree = new qx.ui.tree.Tree();
tree.set({
  width: 500,
  height: 500
});
this.getRoot().add(tree, {left: 10, top: 10});

```
// create and set the tree root
var root = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Desktop");
tree.setRoot(root);

// create some subitems
var f1 = new qx.ui.tree.TreeFolder("Logos");
f1.setMaxHeight(10);
```

And this works. But I am wondering if you can do that with virtual tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the item height for the virtual tree in the "virtual-tree" appearance.

In your theme/Appearance.js:

```
qx.Theme.define("application.theme.Appearance",
{
    extend: qx.theme.modern.Appearance,

    appearances: {
        "virtual-tree": {
            include: "tree",

            style: function (states) {
                return {
                    itemHeight: 10,
                };
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would like to change height for only one item, not for all

Comment: The only idea I have is to use the `qx.ui.tree.core.IVirtualTreeDelegate` delegate with the `configureItem` method. Set a custom decorator or appearance.